# Background for Listings with TeX escape, but caption outside

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, mdframed, backgrounds

Listings does not play well with backgrounds and included math formulas (using mathescape) - there are white horizontal lines because Listings doesn't know how tall the lines are meant to be.  You can use \smash, or (what seems easier) put the entire listing inside an mdframed environment.  This latter is what I've done.  In my case the equations are displayed equations (mimicking the typeset output of a computer algebra system).

However, reviewers of an article have requested that I reference my code listings.  Listings allows this by putting captions and labels as parameters to any given listing.  But this means that the caption is *inside* the mdframed background.  I don't think mdframed has its own referencing method.

Is it possible somehow to work with Listings, mdframed, and cross-references in such a way that:

- The entire listing has a uniform background
- The caption is *outside* the background

Many thanks.